# Push Data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I Have a Database as follow:

```
Root Categories/restaurantid/{text:Item1 AL:Item 2 TEXT:Item 3 ...}
```

So I want to push a Data (variable myKey) in a specific child that item is equal to item 1. I am doing as follow (this.restaurant is the restaurantid):

```
var ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child('/categories/' + this.restaurant);    
var query = ref2.orderByChild('text').equalTo(this.categoria1);
query.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.ref().child('dishes').push({
    mykey: 'true',
```

But I am getting an error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Reference' has no compatible call signatures.

Where I am doing a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In `DataSnapshot`, [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref)
 is a *property* - not a method - so your `push` call should be something like this:

```
snapshot.ref.child('dishes').push({ mykey: 'true', ...
```